# Where does the name "flip-flop" come from?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

After I learn about the DFF (Data Flip-Flop). I understand Flip-Flop as a device that can memorize input data at the rising or falling edge of the clock sequence.

But why call it *flip-flop*? Why not something like *edge-triggered memory circuit*. It's kind of a nick name which is hard to get for a non-English speaker. And in my country, the translated version is kind of twisted.

Could anyone explain the reason of the naming in plain English? Thanks.

Comment: Terms enter the language because they're descriptive and concise.

Comment: @pipe That's a great post. So essentially, this name **emphasizes** the characteristic of the circuit that **to be able to store/switch between 2 stable/opposite states**.

Answer (score -1):

You know flip-flops?
[image]

The actual "flip-flop" name is originated from the sound they made while walking (i.e. by slapping of the sole, foot and floor).

In electronics, a F/F has two "stable" states (0->1 or 1->0) and it alternates from one to another when one or more control signals (e.g. clock) is applied. Let's name it: flip as "0 to 1" and flop as "1 to 0".

Comment: Oh really. So you don't think it's because it _flips_ the state, like how you _flip_ a page to the other side?